# server standard 2008 r2 unable to boot(blue screen error) after configuring raid 1

Tags: operating-system, boot

server standard 2008 r2 unable to boot(blue screen error- STOP: 0x0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A98E8, 0xFFFFFFFFC0000034, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000) after configuring raid 1 & Board Intel - x10DRL-I how to fix

Answer (score 1):

Preinstall the controller driver in the OS *before* upgrading. If you can go back to a normal drive setup, install the driver and reboot and redo the config after. Be sure to have a good backup.

In the best case, you did a system image before such upgrade, thus you can switch back easilly

Comment: That's how I did it - went from Software RAID to `real` RAID. Plug in the card but don't switch. Boot OS and install drivers. Shutdown, switch drives, reboot. Worked like a charm.